# in Ruby, how to extract a key from the Hash having the value

Tags: ruby, hash

i thought i'm a Ruby giant when i wrote this oneliner:

```
# having this hash
hash = { 'Portugal' => 1, 'France' => 2, 'USA' => 3 }

# country_id comes from input
country_name = (hash.select { |k,v| v == country_id.to_i }.first || []).first
```

it does correctly extract the country name and does Not fail if country not found.

i'm totally pleased with it.

however my tutor says it can/should be optimized in terms of readability, length and performance!

what can be clearer/faster than this?

please advise

Comment: Are you certain that the values in your Hash are unique?

Comment: yes, that's a condition of the test, just forgot to mention

Answer (score 9, accepted):

well, seems your tutor is right :)

you can do like this:

```
hash.invert[ country_id.to_i ] # will work on all versions
```

or, as suggested by @littlecegian

```
hash.key( country_id.to_i )    # will work on 1.9 only
```

or, as suggested by @steenslag

```
hash.index( country_id.to_i )  # will work on 1.8 and 1.9, with a warning on 1.9
```

Full example:

```
hash = { 'Portugal' => 1, 'France' => 2, 'USA' => 3 }

%w[2 3 1 blah].each do |country_id|

  # all versions
  country_name = hash.invert[ country_id.to_i ]

  # 1.9 only
  country_name = hash.key( country_id.to_i )

  # 1.8 and 1.9, with a warning on 1.9
  country_name = hash.index( country_id.to_i )


  printf "country_id = %s, country_name = %s\n", country_id, country_name
end
```

will print:

```
country_id = 2, country_name = France
country_id = 3, country_name = USA
country_id = 1, country_name = Portugal
country_id = blah, country_name =
```

### see it running [here](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?lang=ruby&file=in-ruby-how-to-extract-a-key-from-the-hash-having-the-value.rb&run=true)

Comment: Inverting a whole hash just to retrieve one key? Hmm.

Comment: just to make sure it run on all versions. i noted in my answer there are `key` for 1.9 and `index` for 1.8

Comment: Indeed,you edited your answer to include both @littlecegian and my answer, without mentioning so. Bad etiquette IMHO. The silly named `index`-method will work on both Ruby versions, but it will yield a warning on 1.9.

Answer (score 8):

If it is ruby 1.9.3, you can use hash.key(country_id.to_i)

Answer (score 5):

```
hash = { 'Portugal' => 1, 'France' => 2, 'USA' => 3 }
puts hash.invert[3] # "USA"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
hash = { 'Portugal' => 1, 'France' => 2, 'USA' => 3 }
hash.index(2) # => "France"
```

is the Ruby 1.8.x way. The [`index` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Hash.html#method-i-index) is deprecated in 1.9 and being replaced with the `key` method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it makes a lot of sense. I would accept it but i prefer answers "for dumies", with long examples and live demos :)