# Rails 5 get enum key via integer value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model that has the follow enum:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    enum user_type: [:api_user, :web_user]
end
```

When this gets saved into the database, it saves it with the integer value, as expected. I then have a function that accepts the enum like this (in a controller):

```
do_something_useful(type: User.user_types[:web_user], user: user)

def do_something_useful(options)
    some_enum_value = options[:type]
    user = options[:user]

    # Not a practical example.  Just an example to demonstrate the issue.

    # Should return Hello, User! You are a web_user type.
    # But returns, Hello, User! You are a 1 type.
    'Hello, #{user.name}! You are a #{some_enum_value} type.'
end
```

The problem I'm encountering is that the options[:type] is passing the integer value.  I'd like to get the key value of User.user_type by the integer.  Is this possible?

Thanks again.

Comment: Since you're passing in a `user` object, and, assuming that it has been assigned a `user_type`, why don't you interrogate it directly to see what user type it is? `user.user_type => "web_user"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [in Ruby, how to extract a key from the Hash having the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184752/in-ruby-how-to-extract-a-key-from-the-hash-having-the-value)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, did a bit more searching and found this solution:

```
User.user_types.key(options[:type])
```

This will return the key.

Is this the easiest way?  Or another better solution?

Comment: now index method will be deprecated. You should be used the key method. Just updating.

Comment: index is deprecated, use `.key` instead, is the same.